# An ambiguous usage: "Apologia for" vs. "apology of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Suppose someone is using the word "apology" in the theological sense, i.e., a "defense". I'm inclined to use the word "apologia" because it immediately distinguishes it from the typical meaning of "apology", but I'm wondering if this is considered correct:

"In Dr. Salien's apologia of Quebec French..."

or is this better:

"In Dr. Salien's apology for Quebec French..."

You see the problem - Dr. Salien is *defending* Quebec French, not saying that he is sorry for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of both *apology* and *apologia*, the preposition to use is **for**:

> **apology**. 3. a reasoned argument or writing in justification of something, typically a theory or religious doctrine: *a specious apology for capitalism.*

> **apologia**. a formal written defense of one's opinions or conduct: *an apologia for book banning.*

(from the *New Oxford American Dictionary*). I agree that apologia has a clearer meaning if you are discussing an appropriate audience, though it might just sound pedant to the layman.

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about sounding pedantic to a layman with this.  If someone isn’t very familiar with this sense of *apolog[y|ia]*, then *apologia* may have them wracking their memory/dictionary, but *apology* would have them misunderstanding you entirely, which is surely not better!

Comment: @PLL -- `wrack` means "to destroy".  The word you want, meaning to [struggle to remember](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rack_one%27s_brain), is `rack`, as in to torture on a rack.

Answer (score 2):

*Apologia for* is the correct version, but it's also rather obscure and formal. I think you'd be better off using *defense of* or similar. (Though if you're actually talking about Québecois, perhaps the cognate with *apology* would appease any French readers you've got, because Québec French is kinda horrid if you're used to French French.)